# How to call Codenameone java file from a html file?

Tags: codenameone

As like we can nevigate from a codenameone java file to html file by setURL() is there any way to do the same in reverse way i.e from an html file how can i nevigate to an codenameone java file.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/javascript/package-summary.html):

> Calling Java Methods from Javascript
>
> ...
>
> As an example, let's implement a simple logging function:
>
> ```
> JSObject logger = (JSObject)ctx.get("{}"); logger.set("log", new
> JSFunction(){
>
>      public void apply(JSObject self, Object[] args) {
>        String msg = (String)args[0];
>        Log.p("[Javascript Logger] "+msg);
>      }
>  });
>
>  ctx.set("window.logger", logger);
>
>
>  c.executeAndReturnString("logger.log('This is a test message');");
> ```

Comment: Is that a question?